# Take operator on BehaviorSubject Observable not working

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an Angular app where I'm trying to have a list of reservations downloaded from a server to an Angular service.  I want to give all of the components the ability to get the reservation array as an observable and be able to filter and limit the results.  Right now I'm using an BehaviorSubject.  Here is my code.

```
//reservation.service.ts (partial code)

@Injectable()
export class TripService {
  public Trips: Object[] = [];
  public TripSubject: Subject<Object[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Object[]>([]);
  public trips$: Observable<Object[]> = this.TripSubject.asObservable();

  constructor(private apollo: Apollo) { 
    this.apollo.query({query: ReservationQuery}).subscribe((trips: any) => {
      this.Trips = trips.data.allReservations;      
      this.TripSubject.next(this.Trips)
    })
  }
}

//partial component

ngOnInit(): void {   
  this.tripService.trips$.take(3).subscribe(trips => {
    this.Trips = trips
  })
}
```

I get the reservations to populate but I get all of them, not just the 3 I'm wanting by using the take(3). Is there a reason the take operator isn't working?

Comment: Try using `this.tripService.trips$.concatAll().take(3).subscribe(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Yakov Fain has said, you are sending the entire array to the subject in one next() call.

If there is no strong reason for you to transform an array of objects to an array of `Observables`, simply do `.slice()` in your array:

```
ngOnInit(): void {   
  this.tripService.trips$.subscribe(trips => {
    this.Trips = trips.slice(0,3)
  })
}
```

Else, if you really want to transform it to a sequence of Observables (so that you can use `.take(3)`), then you will need to use `.from()`:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.tripService.trips$
        .switchMap(trips => Observable.from(trips));
        .take(3)
        .subscribe(trips=>{
            this.Trips = trips;
        });
}
```

Note that the fundamental difference of getting an array of Objects and an array of Observables is that the latter has multiple emissions of events.

Here's the difference:

### Single Observable of an array of objects, using `.slice()`:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const observables = Observable.of(arr);

observables
    .subscribe(x => {
        this.Trips = x.slice(0, 3)
        console.log(this.Trips);
    });
    //output: [1,2,3] 
    //this.Trips is an array of length 3.
```

### Multiple Observables derived from an array of objects, using `.from()`:

```
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const observables = Observable.from(arr);

observables
    .take(3)
    .subscribe(x => {
        this.Trips = x;
        console.log(this.Trips);
    });
    //output: 1
    //output: 2
    //output: 3
    //You got a single digit output, each are replaces the value of this.Trips on every emission.
```

Comment: This is a great explanation!  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Your service sending the entire array to the subject in one next() call. Accordingly, your subscriber in ngOnInit() gets the entire array and your take(3) operator doesn't do anything because it receives the entire array as one item from the observable stream.

Comment: Is there a way to do what I'm trying to accomplish?